# How does the following proof follow?

Tags: inequality

[image: strong text]

Here is a proof from the book of deep learning by Matus Telgarsky
[Existence of a 2 layered neural network function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GDWnB.png)

How does the part that $\vert x − b_k \vert \lt  \rho(\epsilon/\rho)$ follow?

Comment: It's considered bad form on this site to ask a question by using a link.  Please use MathJax to format mathematics and edit the question by copying the text of the proof into it.  https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since $b_k\leq x < b_{k+1}$, and $b_{k+1}-b_k = \epsilon/\rho$, then $x - b_k < b_{k+1}-b_k = \epsilon/\rho$.

(Remember, $b_j \equiv j\epsilon/\rho$.)

In other words, $b_k$ and $b_{k+1}$ are exactly $\epsilon/\rho$ apart, and $x$ is in between them, so $x$ is even closer to $b_k$.

Comment: Why the downvote?